# Get rid of compiling some set of statements

Tags: c

I have a set of statements for tracing across the code.

Is there any way to get rid of these set of statements before compilation in order to improve the performance?

Will the concept of precompiled headers work out in this scenario?

Thanks in advance
Rupesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually trace is performed in a way similar to this (oversimplified here):

```
#ifdef DISPLAY_TRACES
#define TRACE(x) printf(x)
#else
#define TRACE(x)
#endif
```

Then compile with or without `-DDISPLAY_TRACES` depending on whether you want traces.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Is there a way to apply this concept in .Net world

Answer (score 2):

You can put the tracing in pre-processor macros, and use the pre-processor conditions to select which macros should be used:

```
#ifdef TRACING_ENABLED
# define TRACE(x) printf("TRACE: %s:%d %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, x)
#else
# define TRACE(x)
#endif

void foo()
{
    TRACE("In foo()");
}
```

If `TRACING_ENABLED` is defined, the `TRACE` macro is replaced by a `printf` statement. If `TRACING_EMABLED` is *not* defined, `TRACE` is replaced by an empty line.

Comment: i would take out the ';' in the #define and put it behind the invocation. If you have 'if (cond) TRACE("cond") else TRACE("not cond") it would precompile to if(cond) else which is bad. The other wwould lead to if(cond) ; else ; which is syntactically okay.

Comment: Is there a way that i can keep this code in one file and include this file in another on and use it. Like reusing this code across modules

Comment: @PeterMiehle You're right. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Rupesh Of course. Put the code from `#ifdef` to `#endif` in a header file, and include it anywhere you want to use it.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks i did it and worked out

Answer (score 1):

Use preprocessor directives to remove the tracing statements:

```
#ifdef TRACING_IS_ENABLED
    /* Perform tracing operations. */
#endif
```

Ensure there are no unintended side effects from the tracing statements.

If you want to re-enable the tracing operations define the macro `TRACING_IS_ENABLED`.